# How to overload focusOut using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate, jquery-events

I have a function that listens for focusout event to clear out a form field. This works well by itself. The problem is jQuery Validation plugin binds to focusout event as well to run validations on the field. The validations are always run after I have a chance to clear the field, and so they are always wrong. I am trying to figure out a way to make sure my listener is always executed before the listener for the validation plugin.

So I guess I am wondering if there is a good way of inserting something into a position in the callstack using jQuery? Or perhaps to delay the execution of other bound functions until my function gets a chance to run.

Comment: If you place your bind event after the jQuery validation events binding, it should override them. You want to run both?

Answer (score 0):

You could

1. unbind the validation's focusout event
2. set up a live() - binding for it
3. bind your own event handler

This way the event should bubble up from your handler to the live handler.